# Como atribuir o resultado de uma desestruturação de objeto para uma variável que contenha todos os campos desestruturados?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Dado um objeto `x`:

```
const x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
```

e uma desestruturação:

```
const { a, b } = x;
```

Como faço para salvar esses campos desestruturados em um objeto que os agregue sem precisar fazer:

```
const y = {a, b};
```

---

Tentei fazer

```
const y = { a, b } = x;
```

mas `y` se torna uma referência para `x`, ou seja, `x === y` resulta em `true`

É possível fazer isso no ES6? Não achei nada a respeito na documentação da [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao)

```js
const x = { a: new Date(), b: ['foo', 'bar'], c: { name: 'John' } };
const y = { a, b } = x;

console.log(x === y);
```

Comment: Revertido, o escopo da pergunta não pode ser modificado depois de serem apresentadas respostas. Crie uma [Nova Pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) com outro escopo.

Answer (score 5):

Não é possível fazer isso. Pelo próprio nome do recurso — desestruturação —, você está *removendo*, *desestruturando* um objeto. Não há como usar um "*desestruturador*" como ferramenta para construir outros objetos.

O que você pode fazer é criar uma função que faz isso para você, como um `pick`:

```js
function pick(obj, props) {
  const newObj = {};
  for (const prop of props) newObj[prop] = obj[prop];
  return newObj;
}

const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
console.log(pick(obj, ['a', 'c']));
```

> Seria muito interessante ter uma sintaxe da linguagem para resolver estes pontos que são importantes para mater a qualidade de um código e facilitar a manutenção.

Nesse caso, utilize TypeScript ou alguma outra linguagem. JavaScript nem sempre irá te garantir esse tipo de segurnaça.

Contudo, no caso de você estiver utilizando TypeScript, é possível criar algo um pouco mais complexo que irá te dar o *intellisense* de alguns editores como o VSCode:

```js
function pick<Obj extends { [key: string]: unknown }, Props extends keyof Obj>(
  obj: Obj,
  props: Array<Props>
): { [key in Props]: Obj[key] } {
  const newObj: Pick<Obj, Props> = {} as Pick<Obj, Props>;
  for (const prop of props) newObj[prop] = obj[prop];
  return newObj;
}

const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const result = pick(obj, ['a', 'c']);
console.log(result);
```

Veja funcionando no [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABxhA1gHgPICMBWiApgB5RFgAmAzogN6IDa6RAngFyLVQBOMYAcwC6ncOjBwA7kgC%20AGkQAFHnGS1S5KrRas4wRHnwA%20ABQAoRIjgFOhuRZQq1nAII8eAQ1aZlq6kbMASk4GZjZEfiUnahEDAjDWIUQZegcIBG5EMCJJQ05FNCw7KL8jRABeehSPWgKMHAIFXzUjAG4HYDgeRBN0sEzkJyt9Qb9ArJzDRlHkJMrrfGmnIXbLHiIoEB4kbNyCdpkzMz7MhYr6RA9OAEYFXE4AJgUITgBmZPaTqER16hAAG2%20lVQGBMCwUjAA5B5IQpIRBIUJAp8MnB-kQAHT-OACEy-AFQZFmIA).

Ou pode usar bibliotecas que já existem, como a função [`pick`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick), do Lodash, que também oferece esse comportamento de *intellisense* se você estiver usando TypeScript.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Uma pena que essa funcionalidade não seja suportada nativamente (ou será que não). Você acha que é valido levar esse ponto para o ESNext?

Comment: Luiz Felipe é possível sim olhe a minha resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/451793/137387

Comment: @Luiz Felipe O único incoveniente dessa solução é que os nomes das variaveis desestruturadas (passadas como array de strings para a função pick) não podem ser acessadas pelos intelli senses das IDEs e de alguns editores de textos como o VS Code, por exemplo. E isso para mim é algo que faz muita falta.
O mesmo vale para a sua solução AugustoVasques

Comment: @MichaelPacheco, editei a resposta para tentar contornar esse problema.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, escolher propriedades para se criar um novo objeto e escolher propriedades que não vão fazer parte de um novo objeto são coisas diferentes. O primeiro deles, `pick`, é o que me parece que o AP precisa. O segundo – um tipo de `exclude` –, o que não me parece ser exatamente ao que o AP se referia, é algo diferente.

Comment: Você está equivocado, o objeto sim é criado com as propriedades desejadas. É Algebra Relacional um conjunto disjunto daquilo que não quer é o conjunto do que quer.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, eu entendo o seu ponto, mas selecionar propriedades que devem ser adicionadas e selecionar propriedades que devem ser excluídas são coisas diferentes. Dependendo do tamanho do objeto, excluir todas as propriedades para criar um outro com uma pequena quantidade, essa técnica de exclusão se torna impraticável.

Comment: Mas então não tem que discutir comigo você tem que discutir com os Axiomas de Peano. Quanto ao tamanho não é objeto da questão e sim o recuso de linguagem que na primeira frase disse impossível e digo que é possível.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, ainda penso que "escolher" propriedades seja diferente de "excluir" propriedades. Para mim, são coisas diferentes. Apesar disso, eu entendo a sua resposta, tanto é que votei +1. :)

Comment: Eu não negativei e nem negativo(não havia deixado mas deixei o +1) pois sua resposta é util e funciona, mesmo eu não gostando da primeira frase.

Answer (score 3):

Sim é possível fazer isso no *ES6*.
É uma seleção por exclusão que combina a [desestruturação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao) com um parâmetro [Rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

O objeto original permanecerá inalterado enquanto o objeto resultante será criado com as propriedades do original exceto as que foram desestruturadas.

```js
const x = { a: new Date(), b: ['foo', 'bar'], c: { name: 'John' } };

//Enumere a as propriedades não quer de x
//No parâmetro rest restará o objeto com o que lhe é necessário. 
const {c, ...y} = x;

console.log(y);
console.log(x); // x permanece inalterado.
```

Comment: Uma boa sugestão mas ela se torna impraticável quando o objeto possui muitas chaves e a quantidade de campos indesejados é muito maior que a de desejados

Comment: @MichaelPacheco, mas a pergunta não é "Como atribuir o resultado de uma desestruturação de objeto para uma variável que contenha todos os campos desestruturados?" Está ai a resposta correta! E está provado que sim a linguagem permite fazer.

Comment: Bom, tecnicamente sim, mas no cenário que eu exemplifiquei no comentário anterior essa solução se torna impraticável. Imagine o caso em que você tenha um objeto com 1000 chaves e você quer desestruturar apenas 5 delas. Você iria enumerar todas as outras 995 para obter as que você deseja através do operador rest?

Comment: @MichaelPacheco Aponte onde na pergunta está exemplificado o que alega?

Comment: @MichaelPacheco e na pergunta que marcou como correta ocorre o mesmo problema de ter que enumerar as propriedades desejadas!

Comment: De fato, a solução ainda precisou enumerar as propriedades e não resolveu o problema da forma que eu gostaria. Removi a aceitação da solução.

Comment: Eu não acredito que alguém possa ter dado um negativo. Quem negativou clique no primeiro link que passei e leia até entender a reposta.